# ionic auth gives cross domain error using ionic run

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cors, ionic2

I'm using ionic's auth component to login to Google and Facebook. When making the call towards ionic, it will return a CORS error (I think):

```
POST https://api.ionic.io/auth/login/facebook 
Error: Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-
Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
at v (polyfills.js:3)
at Request.crossDomainError (main.js:187012) 
....
```

However, I'm not running through Ionic serve or live reload, but just plain ionic run android. I understood this should not cause cors error since files are server from the local file system. What could be the cause?

To be fully inclusive, this is the code used:

```
import { Auth,.. } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
this.auth.login('facebook').then(function (success) { ...
```

Comment: I'm having an extremely similar issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: hi @SamBorick, actually I moved away from Ionic auth and am using Firebase now. Yesterday, Ionic announced it wil stop Ionic auth anyway so you'll need to use an alternative solution as well.

Comment: I'm not using ionic auth either, I was just getting the same CORS issue under similar circumstances.  Thanks though!